# Using Gradle to Toggle Between IDEs

Tags: gradle, groovy, dsl

Say I have the following top-level Gradle build file:

```
plugins {
   id "idea"
   //id "eclipse"
}

apply from: "${rootDir}/gradleInclude/intellij.gradle"
//apply from: "${rootDir}/gradleInclude/eclipse.gradle"

subprojects {
  apply plugin: "idea"
  //apply from: "${rootDir}/gradleInclude/eclipse.gradle"
}
```

It is possible to use a single line/variable to toggle between the idea/intellij and eclipse entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did the following:

```
def ide = 'eclipse'
def ideBuildFile = 'eclipse.gradle'
//def ide = 'idea'
//def ideBuildFile = 'intellij.gradle'

plugins {
   id "${ide}"
}

apply from: "${rootDir}/gradleInclude/${ideBuildFile}"

subprojects {
   apply plugin: "${ide}"
}
```